# Does the Consumer Rights Act 2015 cover damaged goods?

Tags: united-kingdom

So the situation is:

I ordered a bathroom vanity unit from an online retailer.  I signed to acknowledge delivery but didn't look inside the boxes until it came time to fit the bathroom - 6 weeks later.  At this time I discovered that the ceramic basin was cracked, which was (as far as I know) not caused by me.

Does the retailer have a liability to replace the basin under the Consumer Rights Act 2015?  It says that goods have to be "of satisfactory quality", but the retailer is saying that this covers "faulty items and not damaged ones" and that they therefore have no liability to replace the basin.  However I have also read that the Act requires that the goods not be damaged.  Which is it?

Comment: Would you say that damaged goods are “of satisfactory quality”?

Comment: A damaged item is clearly faulty.